# Assign child node from a JSON response to project variable everytime a request is sent in SoapUI

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soap, soapui

I am new to soapUI and still figuring it out.
Is it possible to extract data from a JSON response and assign it to a project variable which can further be used in another request. In my case it's an authentication token.

Appreciate all your responses.

Found nothing specific on internet regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using property transfer.

Add a property transfer step, and select the response of the previous REST request, and use Xquery to get the child node, and assign it to the project variable.

For eg:

```
{"menu": {  
  "id": "file",  
  "value": "File",  
  "popup": {  
    "menuitem": [  
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateDoc()"},  
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},  
      {"value": "Save", "onclick": "SaveDoc()"}  
    ]  
  }  
}}
```

Use the Xquery, "$.menu.popup.menuitem.value", to access the respective child node.